# Will the measure preserving map preserve Lebesgue density points?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Here is my question:

If there is a measure preserving map $f$ from a compact subset $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself, will the subset of its Lebesgue density points (denoted by $K$)be an f-invariant set?

By the Lebesgue density theorem, $m(K)=m(M)$, and by the measure-preserving property, $m(K)=m(f^{-1}(K))=m(M)$. Since they are full measure set, I thought maybe we can have $f^{-1}(K)=K$, could anyone give me some idea about it?

Comment: Yes, I also think that things can be mess if $K$ isn't compact, but will the compactness can permit a better result?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it's right. Because for the disc D, K is fixed to be the open disc. And if you choose M to be the closed upper right quadrant,  the problem doesn't hold because $f$ doesn't map M to itself.